# Georasters: RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

Tags: numpy, anaconda, runtime-error, spyder, python-3.7

I have made an environment based on ArcGIS Pro, which has

```
Python 3.7.10, 
arcpy 2.8,
arcgispro 2.8,
gdal 2.3.3
```

I need to use georasters, but I do not know which version to install. I tried installing the default and now I have, georaster 0.5.15. However, whenever I import the library, I end up getting

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
```

I searched it online wherein they suggested to upgrade numpy, but when I did that, the whole environments stopped working. What should I do? I am planning to downgrade numpy and georasters, but I do know which version to use.